# Can I export a model and texture from a terrain file built in Unity3D?

Tags: unity, xna-4.0, monogame, terrain-rendering

I am mostly familiar with building my level maps within unity, and have become quite use to its inbuilt terrain creator, in both generating my terrain, and spraying a texture on to it.

I am making a game using MonoGame XNA, and would like to use a terrain map I built with Unity. I would have to recover the file, however, and have not been able to find anything to support being able to, in the first place.

Can I export my terrain file with its texture, in any way, to use in XNA MonoGame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible to export Unity terrain as an obj file to use in other game engines :)

Follow this Link :- 
[TerrainObjExporter](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=TerrainObjExporter)